# How to create own model that can authenticate like admin user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I create own model user but can't authenticate it like in admin user

```
# myapss/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from django.db.models.manager import Manager

class MyOwnManager(Manager):
    ...
class MyOwnUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    ...

    objects = MyOwnManager()
```

I want to authenticate this model without using AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser

```
#myapps/views.py
from .models import MyOwnUser

def login(request):
    # Authentication
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There are certain steps that you need to follow in order to create a custom user model in Django. Please have a look at the following document and find the detailed instruction on what you have to do in order to develop a custom user model:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

2. I would also recommend to have a look at this tutorial:

https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

3. You are trying to build a User mode from scratch, it is quite complicated and redundant, because, effectively you will end up writing your own code reproducing AbstractBaseUser class functionality.